# How to mock object for @Autowired in junit 5 unit test?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

I am doing unit test for my spring boot service class using junit 5. Inside service class i am autowiring object for calling methods in other class. In test case @Mock is not creating object for @Autowired class. Here i am giving my code.

my service class :

```
@Service
public class BarcodeReaderService {

    @Autowired
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor;

    public String dummy(String name) {
        System.out.println("function call"); //print success
        return imageProcessor.dummy(name);   //Null pointer Exception
    }
    }
```

my component class :

```
@Component
public class ImageProcessor {

    public String dummy(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("function call ImageProcessor"); //Not coming to this line
        return name;
    }
    }
```

my unit test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import com.inslab.reader.barcodereader.imageprocessing.ImageProcessor;
import com.inslab.reader.barcodereader.service.BarcodeReaderService;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BarcodeReaderServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    BarcodeReaderService barcodeReaderService;

    @Mock
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor;


    @Test
    void testDummy() {
        Mockito.when(imageProcessor.dummy("name")).thenReturn("name");
        String name = barcodeReaderService.dummy("name");
        Assertions.assertEquals("name", name);
    }

}
```

pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.inslab.reader</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcodereader</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>barcodereader</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

While running this test i am getting null pointer exception in imageProcessor.dummy(name);

Comment: Ofcourse you are getting a nullpointerexpeption as you are creating a new instance inside your test method instead of reusing the one from the class with the mocks injected. Also running it with the `SpringExtension` doesn't add anything as this isn't a spring based test but rather a regular unit test.

Comment: I removed this  BarcodeReaderService barcodeReaderService = new BarcodeReaderService(); from the test. Not the error is expected<name> but was: <null>. If i try remove this @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class), i am getting null pointer exception in this line String name = barcodeReaderService.dummy("name");.

Comment: You haven't only removedthe extendwith also your setup method is gone, that should still be there to setup your mocks.

Comment: Ok i will add that too and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added @SpringBootTest at the begining of my class. It worked. Make sure your import are correct for junit 5. here my code,

```
package com.inslab.reader;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.inslab.reader.ImageProcessor;
import com.inslab.reader.IReader;

@SpringBootTest
class BarcodeReaderServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    BarcodeReaderService barcodeReaderService;

    @Mock
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor;

    @BeforeEach //instead of @Before have to use @BeforeEach in junit5
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testDummy() {
        Mockito.when(imageProcessor.dummy("name")).thenReturn("name");
        String name = barcodeReaderService.dummy("name");
        Assertions.assertEquals("name", name);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to register the `MocktioExtension` for your test like:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BarcodeReaderServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    BarcodeReaderService barcodeReaderService;

    @Mock
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor;

    @Test
    void testDummy() {
        when(imageProcessor.dummy("name")).thenReturn("YOUR_OUTCOME");
        String name = barcodeReaderService.dummy("name");
        Assertions.assertEquals("YOUR_OUTCOME", name);
    }

}
```

Also don't use `new` in the test to create the instance of your class under test and rather use your field variable `barcodeReaderService`. When you work with Mockito you also have to specify the behavior of your Mock, otherwise, it will always return `null`.

Comment: I did the same thing. Now i am getting failure trace - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.support.AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(Ljava/util/Optional;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Optional;
 at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.retrieveAnnotationFromTestClasses(MockitoExtension.java:183)

Comment: make sure to only use JUnit 5 in your test, and don't import anything from `org.junit` and rather from `org.junit.jupiter` as the `@Test` annotation might still come from JUnit 4

Comment: if that does not help, please add your `pom.xml` and the full code (including import section) of your test class to your question

Comment: I added my pom.xml and import of test class

Comment: okay and what is currently the error: the null pointer or the NoSuchMethodErrod?

Comment: No i am getting failure trace with more lines. I comment first 2 lines and in between lines that i think the error.  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.support.AnnotationSupport.findAnnotation(Ljava/util/Optional;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Optional;
 at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.retrieveAnnotationFromTestClasses(MockitoExtension.java:183)                                                                                         Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:230)

Answer (score 0):

Use @InjectMocks for your Service class in the test class, all other @Autowired inside your service class should be @Mock in test class